# How to set Sql Server Job Schedule Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

We have an `Sql Server` Job which runs for an entire season. The end date of the season may be change this year. I need to integrate this change in `Job` Schedule.  Is there any way to determine `start-date` and `end-date` the `Job` dynamically?i.e passing them as parameters to `sql-server` job.
How to achieve this?

thanks for the help

Comment: we just discuss the same issue here,  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638329/schedule-sql-job-in-a-user-configured-time-intervals-everyday

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[sp_update_schedule (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187354.aspx)

You need to run another job to update the schedule of the first Job according to your business requirements